# RTM and study design issue

Tags: bias, case-control-study

I was asked to estimate "regression to the mean" (RTM) error for the purpose of measuring program efficacy for reducing spending among the highest spending individuals. Given the constraints of the data (administrative data set), I have identified the following issues:

1. selection bias: patients choice determines whether a program is given; and,
2. unable to separate program from RTM effect: lack of a "true" comparison group

Given these constraints, I foresee many challenges to this project. I have, however, read this [article](https://ceprofs.civil.tamu.edu/dlord/papers/park_lord_speed_ba_trb.pdf), and I want to know if I could conduct something similar to meet the requirements of this ask. Specifically, I am wondering if the following procedure will work:

1. Estimate the RTM for all data, and adjust the outcome variable (spending in $)
2. Identify the "highest" spenders, which was proposed as top 10% spenders
3. Assign "treatment to those who were in the program and assign "control" to those who were not in the program (control)
4. Assess differences while adjusting for "similar" characteristics to try and control for some of the selection bias, while accepting some residual bias (MANOVA?)

The most important step right now would be to estimate a value for RTM; however, I would like to also know what are some options I could take in order to solve the longer-term problem.

Thanks in advance.